# Return Results Of Consecutive Days Per User

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table such as the following:

```
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 | id | employeeNumber | transactionTime         |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  1 |           1234 | 2016-02-23 15:11:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  2 |           1234 | 2016-02-22 11:01:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  3 |           1235 | 2016-02-22 07:22:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  4 |           1236 | 2016-02-20 09:16:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  5 |           1236 | 2016-02-19 11:01:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  6 |           1236 | 2016-02-18 11:44:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  7 |           1236 | 2016-02-17 12:12:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  8 |           1236 | 2016-02-16 11:09:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 |  9 |           1236 | 2016-02-15 11:19:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
 | 10 |           1236 | 2016-02-14 09:12:00.000 |
 +----+----------------+-------------------------+
```

I Need to find a way to return the number of consecutive days that each employee logged a transaction over the past 2 weeks. Such as this:

```
 +------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
 | days |employeeNumber| startTime               | endTime                 |
 +------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
 |  2   |         1234 | 2016-02-22 11:01:00.000 | 2016-02-23 15:11:00.000 |
 +------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
 |  1   |         1235 | 2016-02-22 11:01:00.000 | 2016-02-22 11:01:00.000 |
 +------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
 |  7   |         1236 | 2016-02-14 09:12:00.000 | 2016-02-20 09:16:00.000 |
 +------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I have been working with the following query, but It only returns a single user and doesn't take into account only the past 2 weeks.

```
WITH 
dates(date) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(transactionTime AS DATE)
    FROM Fuel.dbo.comdata
    WHERE employeeNumber = 123456
),
groups AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rn,
    DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date), date) AS grp,
    date
    FROM dates
)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS consecutiveDates, 
MIN(date) AS minDate, MAX(date) AS     maxDate
FROM groups
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC
```

Any help is appreciated.

### UPDATE

So I have found the following query very helpful thanks to Gordon Linoff's answer below. However I notice that the Min/Max Dates don't match up to the number of consecutive days. As shown Here with live data:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT employeeNumber, COUNT(*) AS consecutiveDays, 
    MIN(transactionTime) AS startTime, MAX(transactionTime) AS endTime
    FROM (
        SELECT cd.*, DATEADD(DAY, -DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY     
        employeeNumber ORDER BY transactionTime), CAST(transactionTime AS  
        DATE)) AS grp
        FROM Fuel.dbo.comdata cd
        WHERE transactionTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())
    ) cd
    GROUP BY employeeNumber, grp
) AS tbl1
WHERE consecutiveDays >= 7

 +--------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
 | empNum | days| startTime               | endTime                |
 +--------+-------------------------------+------------------------+
 | 16742  | 7   | 2016-04-28 17:00:00.000 | 2016-05-07 17:04:00.000|
 +--------+-------------------------------+------------------------+
 | 15056  | 8   | 2016-04-27 13:03:00.000 | 2016-05-08 09:51:00.000|
 +--------+-------------------------------+------------------------+
```

As you can see the number of consecutive days does not match the start/end time. Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with the difference using row number approaches (assuming there is never more than one record per day per employee):

```
select employee, count(*) as numdays,
       min(timestamp) as startTime, max(timestamp) as endTime
from (select cd.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     - row_number() over (partition by employee order by transactionTime),
                     cast(transactionTime as date)
                    ) as grp
      from Fuel.dbo.comdata cd
     ) cd
group by employee, grp;
```

The idea is to generate a series of sequential numbers for each employee based on the transactionTime.  The difference between this and the transactionTime is constant, when the transactions are on consecutive days.

If you can have multiple transactions on the same day, then you can use `dense_rank()`.

If you have duplicates on the same day:

```
select employee, count(*) as numdays,
       min(timestamp) as startTime, max(timestamp) as endTime
from (select cd.*,
             dateadd(day,
                     - dense_rank() over (partition by employee order by cast(transactionTime as date)),
                     cast(transactionTime as date)
                    ) as grp
      from Fuel.dbo.comdata cd
     ) cd
group by employee, grp;
```

Comment: Ok, that is exactly what I am looking for. However, there can definitely be multiple transactions per customer on the same day. So I replaced row_over() with dense_rank(). Would you mind explaining the difference between row_over() and dense_rank()?

Comment: Check here. https://blog.jooq.org/2014/08/12/the-difference-between-row_number-rank-and-dense_rank/

Comment: I have updated my original post. The start/end times are not matching up with the consecutive days. Why is this?

Comment: @dschuett maybe you should read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that way we can check why you are getting the wrong result.